# Testing : How to create fake object context using TypeMock for EF4 model

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-4, mocking, typemock-isolator

I am using EF4 in my application and I want to make test cases for DAL methods, which generally hit the database to get data. I am using the Typemock framework for Mocking. I want to mock database call and only want to test queries. E.g.:

```
ObjectContext.Where(u => u.code == Code)
```

For doing this, I need to make Fake `ObjectContext` for EF Models and want to fill some fake data in Fake `ObjectContext` so that we can execute our queries (LINQ) on fake `ObjectContext`. Kindly suggest how can I can create fake object context(Using TypeMock framework) and fill data in the entities.

For example, I have the following method:

```
protected IObjectSet<T> CreateObjectSet<T>() where T : EntityBase 
{ 
    return _context.CreateObjectSet<T>(); 
}
```

And I am creating a test case to mock _context, however _context is null. My test case is:

```
var fakeInMemoryBlogs = GetUsers();    
var fakeContext = Isolate.Fake.Instance<SecurityEntitiesUOW>(); 
var fakeGenericRepository = Isolate.Fake.Instance<GenericRepository>
    (Members.CallOriginal, ConstructorWillBe.Called, fakeContext); 
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeContext.Context.CreateObjectSet<SecUser>()) 
    .WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(fakeInMemoryBlogs.AsQueryable());
```

Comment: The question is if it makes sense to fake it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766478/unit-testing-dbcontext and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904139/fake-dbcontext-of-entity-framework-4-1-to-test/6904479#6904479

Comment: Good point on the LINQ-to-Entities Vs LINQ-to-Objects difference when mocking the context, Ladislav. Maybe encapsulate the LINQ queries and test those against a real database and mock those queries when testing the business logic.

Comment: Hi, I want to create Fake ObjectContext for unittesting using TypeMock and fill all required entities in fake ObjectContext, so that I can verify lamda expressions and include clause only without hitting database. Kindly suggest me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been asked a couple of times before. Did some searching and came up with the following resources:

**Introducing Entity Framework Unit Testing with TypeMock Isolator**

http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Introducing-Entity-Framework-Unit-Testing-with-TypeMock-Isolator.aspx

**Abstract the ObjectContext by using the Repository Pattern**

[EF4 - possible to mock ObjectContext for unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703100/ef4-possible-to-mock-objectcontext-for-unit-testing)

**How to mock ObjectContext or ObjectQuery in Entity Framework?**

[How to mock ObjectContext or ObjectQuery<T> in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415432/how-to-mock-objectcontext-or-objectqueryt-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Thanks, but I have a method something like :                protected IObjectSet<T> CreateObjectSet<T>() where T : EntityBase
        {
            return _context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        }, and I am creating test case to mock _context with fake ObjectContext, It is showing _context is null.

Comment: My test case something e.g:     var fakeInMemoryBlogs = GetUsers();

            //(2) create fake context
            var fakeContext = Isolate.Fake.Instance<SecurityEntitiesUOW>();
            var fakeGenericRepository = Isolate.Fake.Instance<GenericRepository>(Members.CallOriginal, ConstructorWillBe.Called, fakeContext);
            //(3) Setup expected call to MyBlogContext.Blogs property through the fake context
            Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeContext.Context.CreateObjectSet<SecUser>())
                   .WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(fakeInMemoryBlogs.AsQueryable());

Comment: Hi, I want to create Fake ObjectContext for unittesting using TypeMock and fill all required entities in fake ObjectContext, so that I can verify lamda expressions and include clause only without hitting database. Kindly suggest me. Thanks